# Why is my jquery post not sending data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know it is not sending the post values because in my php I have an echo statement that isn't being called.

```
function common_set_total(doc_string)
{
  var parser = new DOMParser(); //create a new DOMParser
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(doc_string, "application/xml"); //convert the string to xml
  $.ajax
  (
    {
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      url:  SITE_URL + "/system/xml/price",
      data: { xml: doc, apptype: "frame", session_id: session_id}
    }
  ).done(function( msg ) 
  {
      $("#total").html("$" + msg); //Set the total
  });

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console to see if the request is actually going through?

Comment: where is session_id coming from?

Comment: Why are you converting a string to a dom and than it will be converted back to a string in the post? get rid of that and just use the string.

Comment: I'd suggest you also add `$.ajax(...).done(...).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { ..log those to console.. });` to your call. That might give you the info you need to debug this.

Comment: jQuery's Ajax can only proccess data across domains if the datatype is setted to be JSONP. See the "async" section of http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Rooster: session_id is coming from the top of the code.

Comment: @Eric Wu: It is on the same domain.

Comment: @Ingmars it doesn't fail, I get back something from the php so it is not failing

Answer (score 0):

```
function common_set_total(doc_string)
{
  $.ajax
  (
    {
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      url:  SITE_URL + "/system/xml/price",
      data: "xml=" + doc_string + "&apptype=frame&session_id=" + session_id
    }
  ).done(function( msg ) 
  {
      $("#total").html("$" + msg); //Set the total
  });

}
```